# Vue Js fetch data onclick and append inside a modal

Tags: dom, vue.js, vuejs2, append

I have two components, one is parent component and another one is child component which is a modal popup.

**Parent component**

```
<parent-component>

      <!-- this is a modal popup -->
      <child-component v-bind:message="childMessage"></child-component>

      <a href="#" @click="openModal(5)">Open model</a>

</parent-component>
<script>
   export default {
      data: function() {
        return {
           childMessage:{}
        }
      },
      methods:{
       openModal: function(id){
            axios.get('api/message/'+id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.childMessage = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
            })
            this.showModal = true
        }
     }
   }
</script>
```

---

**Child component**

```
<!-- this is a popup modal -->
<child-component>
    <h1>{{ message.title }}</h1>
</child-component>
<script>
   export default {
  props:{
    message: {},
  }
</script>
```

---

In parent component, I trigger the modal and request ajax at the same time.
And I can pass the ajax data to child component correctly.

But if I open the console, there is an error

**Cannot read property 'title' of undefined**

(Although I can see the data is working fine and it's already in html page)

It seems the appending data `{{ childMessage.title }}` run first (before the ajax request).

1 - How can I append the data correctly, probably after the ajax request.

2 - Do I need to check the condition for **undefined value**?

Comment: `v-bind:message="childMessage"`, not `this.childMessage`

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake, I've changed it. I can get the data correctly, the problem is the error in the console - "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".

Comment: Can you show data in `response.data`?

Comment: Btw,   `props:{ message: {} }`, your `message` is an object, not a string

Comment: As I already get the data, the problem is not from my typo.. Sorry for my mistakes in this question. This is the example components. Thanks for helping me out @ittus,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you use `showModal` but I suppose it's a sort of switch to display or not the `child-component`. If it's the case the error can come from the fact that you set `showModal` to true just after the call to the API. But this call is asynchronous you should probably move `this.showModal = true` in the success callback under `this.childMessage = response.data;`.
If you do that the message prop will be initialize at the moment the child component is rendered.

Also pay attention to your prop type, as @ittus mention `message` seems to be a String according to the default value in the `child-component` but you use it like an object in the template.

Comment: It's a trick :D, I run the **showModal** after the ajax call but it doesn't work. And now, I move **showModal** in the success callback and the error was gone. Thanks @budgw.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to check the condition for `undefined` value because child component is being rendered before the `message` API call ends. You can do it in this way,

```
<child-component>
    <h1 v-if = "message">{{ message.title }}</h1>
</child-component>
```